# Kali Linux 2019.3 Wi-Fi Driver Issue

Tags: linux, windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, kali-linux

So I have recently installed Kali Linux 2019.3 on my Windows 10 Operating system. I decided to do a dual boot with it as well with 40 GB partitioned for it dedicating 16 GB of memory to the OS. (UEFI on my board). Everything in the install process was okay except for the Networking section which was a Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol error apparently saying that there was no DHCP configured on the router.

Despite that, the operating system works perfectly fine although, there is no internet access what so ever. I do not, on my Windows 10 OS or at all, use Ethernet, but rather Wi-Fi (Unfortunately). When launching and booting into Linux Kali, I login and there is not option for internet what so ever. Here is the screen below.

[image: My View]

In conclusion I believe there is an error with detecting the wireless network driver or card which is on my motherboard. I'm not sure if it's an installation process for installing drivers, or if there's an error with detecting the actual card itself. That or the driver.

Comment: lspci doesn't show the wireless adapter, but lsusb shows the wifi adapter.

Comment: It’s a USB off of the motherboard

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the drivers for the RTL-88xx is still a **work in progress**.

There is currently a GitHub page for these drivers: https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au

It claims it supports network cards (8811au, 8812au, 8814au and 8821au chipsets) with monitor mode and injection support.

You will need the DKMS package installed.

**apt-get install DKMS** & **apt-get install git**

Download the driver package:
**git clone -b v5.6.4.1 https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git**

In order to install the driver open a terminal in the directory with the source code, and execute the following command:

**./dkms-install.sh**

If that doesn't work for you, follow the instructions in the git project "readme.md" for using the **make command**. I should also mention there are abnormal instructions in the readme to put this card into monitor mode, **airmon-ng can't be used**.

I might add, if you do not need this card for packet injection you might just want to buy a USB/card online that's already in the supported adapter list. I picked up a TP-LINK wn722 V1 for about $10 on eBay. It works flawlessly without any hassle!

Comment: Ok do I need Ethernet plugged in to do that? If so would power line adapters work?

Comment: Power line adapters should work, and yes you will need to connect it to the internet.

Comment: Awesome I'll try to find some power line adapters tomorrow for it to work. Is there any good power line adapters you would recommend I have a NetGear Nighthawk router.

Comment: I personally don't recommend them, in most cases it is like wireless. They claim a Mbps rate, and it's usually much lower in reality than the claim. I own a pair from tp-link, they get about 30% of the advertised speed.

Comment: So what should I do I can’t run an Ethernet and the drivers for WiFi are somewhat of a pain to install

Comment: Run it temporary, or move the computer closer to the Internet to install them. It shouldn't take more than 10 mins.

Comment: I could do that but if I got a 1200 MBS power line adapter it would be 600 MBS which is the same speed as my wireless adapter?

Comment: It is your choice, it seems silly to buy an adapter to download something that will take a couple minutes. Why not just use Windows to download it via WiFi, save the drivers to a USB stick and transfer it to Kali that way to install them.

Comment: Do I need an ethernet cable running while installing the drivers from the USB stick. And also I was going to buy a power line adapter anyways for the purpose of consistent internet stability.

Answer (score 0):

Check the output when entering entering the following command:

```
ifconfig
```

Here you can see all your networking drivers, which are currently active. There sould be an adapter called:

```
wlan0 or sometimes wlan1:
```

If there is nothing to see, if possible input an ethernet cable and run

```
apt-get update
```

At least after this update, you should be able to connect to a wireless network with your pc.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot run an Ethernet cable from the router to my computer.

Comment: @fbleb, Unfortunately these instructions **will not** help you, ifconfig only displays cards/adapters that have working drivers in the OS, and **apt-get update** only updates the repositories list of packages, **not** drivers or anything else...

Comment: Ok update I ran a 60 ft CAT 5e across my floor. GOOD News: Ethernet Works! BAD News: Wi Fi still does not. I tried to download drivers for the AC 600 WLAN Adapter from the manufacturer and none of them are supported (RTL 8811au)

Answer (score -1):

There is no error. Network services not working out of the box is [intended behavior](https://docs.kali.org/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux):

> **Network services disabled by default:** Kali Linux contains systemd hooks that disable network services by default. These hooks allow us to install various services on Kali Linux, while ensuring that our distribution remains secure by default, no matter what packages are installed. Additional services such as Bluetooth are also blacklisted by default.